# How to retain file name using Perl replacement for grep

Tags: perl, command-line, grep

Consider the following command line output using grep:

```
[gjempty@gjempty]$ find . -name "*.php" | xargs grep __construct | tail
./ilserverd/src/php/ImageLoopIntegrationService.php:  public function __construct($input, $output=null) {
./ilserverd/src/php/ImageLoopIntegrationService.php:  public function __construct($vals=null) {
./ilserverd/src/php/ImageLoopIntegrationService.php:  public function __construct($vals=null) {
./ilserverd/src/php/ImageLoopIntegrationService.php:  public function __construct($vals=null) {
./ilserverd/src/php/ImageLoopIntegrationService.php:  public function __construct($vals=null) {
./ilserverd/src/php/ImageLoopIntegrationService.php:  public function __construct($handler) {
./ilserverd/src/php/il_server_types.php:  public function __construct($vals=null) {
./ilserverd/src/php/il_server_types.php:  public function __construct($vals=null) {
./utilities/studio/legacy/full_bleed_update_photobook_themes.php:    public function __construct() {
./utilities/studio/legacy/full_bleed_update_photobook_themes.php:        parent::__construct();
```

This is my first step in trying to extract constructor arguments, and because it will require a number of steps, I'm trying to use Perl as an improvement over grep.  But first, I want to retain the file names so I can refer back to those in my final "report" output.

But when I switch to the following Perl one-liner the file names are no longer part of the output.  How can I retain them and still use Perl as a command-line replacement for grep?

```
[gjempty@gjempty]$ find . -name "*.php" | xargs perl -wnl -e '/__construct/ and print' | tail
  public function __construct($input, $output=null) {
  public function __construct($vals=null) {
  public function __construct($vals=null) {
  public function __construct($vals=null) {
  public function __construct($vals=null) {
  public function __construct($handler) {
  public function __construct($vals=null) {
  public function __construct($vals=null) {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using `$ARGV` as:

```
perl -wnl -e '/__construct/ and print "$ARGV: $_"'
```

Answer (score 3):

Building a better version of grep in Perl has already been done; it's called [ack](http://betterthangrep.com).

```
ack --type=php __construct
```

Or, if you want the filename with each matched line (instead of as a heading):

```
ack --type=php --nogroup __construct
```

Note that you don't need the `find ... | xargs ...` portions, either. The `--type=php` argument takes the place of the find.